# how to check the Variable is or not in the Memory using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, memory, google-maps-markers

i want to check the marker(google maps v3) is or not in the Memory  when i zoom in map  and can't see them .

so  what can i do  ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the markers that you add to the map in an array. You need to add a bounds_changed event listener with a function that searches that array and checks if marker coordinates are within your map bounds. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script>

            var map;
            markers = [];
            function initialize(){
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                //if creating multiple markers you would do marker creation and storage in a loop
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: latlng,
                    title: "Marker 1"
                });
                var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.2, 150.644),
                    title: "Marker 2"
                });
                //save your marker to an array to keep track of your markers - i am assuming all markers are initially visible
                markers.push({
                    visible: true,
                    marker: marker1
                })
                markers.push({
                    visible: true,
                    marker: marker2
                })

                //watch for zoom change event
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
                    checkBounds()

                })

            }

            function checkBounds(){

                //get bounds for a new zoom level
                bounds = map.getBounds();
                //loop through markers array to check if they are still in bounds (visible)
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                   m = markers[i].marker
                    if (bounds.contains(m.position)) {
                        //do something here for markers that are visible
                        markers[i].visible = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        //do something here for markers that are not visible
                        markers[i].visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            //this is just to show which markers are visible and which ones are not
            function show(){
                htmlVisible = ""
                htmlHidden = ""
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                     m = markers[i].marker
                    if (markers[i].visible) {

                        htmlVisible += m.title + "\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        htmlHidden += m.title + "\n";
                    }

                }
                alert("Visible markers:\n" + htmlVisible + "\n" + "Markers out of bounds:\n" + htmlHidden)
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;">
        </div>
        <input type=button onclick="show()" value="List visible/out of bounds markers">
    </body>
</html>
```